# Why Receive Actor method in akka behaves like a val?

Tags: scala, akka

I am wondering why the receive method of akka Actor in this code behaves like a val ?

```
import akka.actor.{ ActorRef, ActorSystem, Props, Actor }
import scala.concurrent.duration._


// Define Actor Messages
case class WhoToGreet(who: String)


// Define Greeter Actor
class Greeter extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    println("in receive")
    receiveHandler
  }


  def receiveHandler: Receive = {
    case WhoToGreet(who) => println(s"Hello $who")
  }
}

object HelloAkkaScala extends App {

  // Create the 'hello akka' actor system
  val system = ActorSystem("Hello-Akka")

  // Create the 'greeter' actor
  val greeter = system.actorOf(Props[Greeter], "greeter")

  // Send WhoToGreet Message to actor
  greeter ! WhoToGreet("Akka")

  greeter ! WhoToGreet("Akka")

  greeter ! WhoToGreet("Akka")


  //shutdown actorsystem
  system.terminate()

}
```

The output:

```
in receive
Hello Akka
Hello Akka
Hello Akka
```

when it is supposed to be:

```
in receive
Hello Akka
in receive
Hello Akka
in receive
Hello Akka
```

while the receive is a def.

Any idea about this behavior, why the def here compute like a val ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`receive` returns a PartialFunction[Any, Unit], and that PartialFunction is seeded as the Actors behavior (can be changed with context.become/unbecome).

The reason for it to be perceived as a `val` is that the PartialFunction instance is reused until changed.

Comment: Thanks, but why in this [code](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/scala/2.12.0/14e) it behaves like a def ?

Comment: The code you linked to is completely unrelated to PartialFunctions, you can prove this by changing the return type to Unit. Your methods execute side effects (printlns) outside of the PartialFunction. Akka invokes the (cached) PartialFunction.

Comment: Can you please, take a look in the code above, I have changed the Partial type to :    type Partial = PartialFunction[Any, Unit]
I can't see the difference

Comment: It seems like there was a misunderstanding, I didn't say change it to PartialFunction[Any, Unit], I said change it to Unit.

Comment: I still not seeing the difference between the receive method in Actor Class and the hello method in my example, both of them return a PartialFunction[Any, Unit]

Comment: The difference is that Akka actually uses the returned PartialFunction.

Comment: The key is that `receive` is evaluated *once and only once* when an actor is instantiated.  The actor then internally caches the `PartialFunction` returned by `receive`.